# XPath returns no result for some elements with scrapy shell

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using scrapy shell to extract data of the following web page:

https://www.apo-in.de/product/acc-akut-600-brausetabletten.24170.html

Most data works, but there is a table in the lower part which content (the PZN e.g.) I seem not to be able to extract.

```
scrapy shell
fetch('https://www.apo-in.de/product/acc-akut-600-brausetabletten.24170.html')
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="accordionContent5e95408f73b10"]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/text()').extract()
```

It returns: `[]`

[image]

I also downloaded the page to view as scrapy sees it:

```
scrapy fetch --nolog https://www.apo-in.de/product/acc-akut-600-brausetabletten.24170.html > test.html
```

Although it looks OK in HTML and although I can grab it in chrome, it does not work in scrapy shell.

How can I retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem You have encountered is that id 'accordionContent5e95408f73b10' is dynamically generated. So, id in Your browser and scrapy's response are different ones.

In common cases there is good workaround to write xpath with "substring search" (`//*[contains(@id, 'accordionContent')]`), but in this case there are a lot of such ids.

I can advise to write more complicated xpath.

```
//div[@id='accordion']/div[contains(@class, 'panel')][1]/div[contains(@id, 'accordionContent')]/div[@class='panel-body']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td
```

What this xpath do:

1. Find all "subpanels" with descriptions `//div[@id='accordion']/div[contains(@class, 'panel')]`;
2. We get first "subpanel" (where PZN is located) and navigate into table with data: `//div[@id='accordion']/div[contains(@class, 'panel')][1]/div[contains(@id, 'accordionContent')]/div[@class='panel-body']/table`;
3. And last part is retrieving first tr's td.

By the way, xpath can be simplified to `//div[@id='accordion']/div[contains(@class, 'panel')][1]//table/tbody/tr[1]/td` . But i've written full xpath for more accurate understanding what we're navigating.

Comment: And to complete, a shortest alternative : `//td[preceding-sibling::th[.="PZN"]]`

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand what happened and also I got the PZN via your last comment. Please allow me 2 questions:
1. How did you retrieve the corresponding divs and IDs. Is there an easy way without looking into such a huge amount of code?
2. Please explain the .= syntax. I looked up preceding-sibling syntax but could not find the .=
The last one looks like the best and easiest solution.

Comment: 1. I retrieved divs and ids by analyze page's DOM tree. Required content is located in div with id 'accordion'. This id is unique, so we can use it.  E.Wiest gave much more short and faster xpath, but with using special xpath operator preceding-sibling. Let me explain what his expression does.   It finds TD tag which has preceding tag TH with text 'PZN'.  Operator '.=' is similar to 'text()' (```//td[preceding-sibling::th[text()="PZN"]]``` finds the same)